# Error Code when Web Scraping and Trying to Combine Datasets

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to pull data from a website to create a csv for analysis. I have code from a data pull two years ago, but it seems the web pages have changed. I have the code from before and it looks like things are working until I try and merge the datasets at the end to create one file. I have the code below as well as the error message. Very new to this so not sure if there is more that would be helpful, but I have the rest of the code if that would be helpful.

Any and all help is appreciated!

[image: Merging Datasets Code]

[image: Error Code]

Comment: Are you certain that  `player_page_y` label exists in the merged dataframe?

Comment: I am not which is a big part of my problem. I am using the code from a few years ago for the same data pull, but player data from a few years ago as well. My guess is the webpage changed/they coded different this year and I am just trying to figure out what the code is to create the correct pull. I did try player_page and I think that works now, but I am still having trouble getting all the way to the data pull.